# Guarantee CPU response?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, assembly

**Note:** I prefer C++ (the code bellow is C++) but If anyone manages to do the following in **any** common language, I am OK.

Here is the idea:

a) timer starts.
b) function executes and takes **always** less than 0.1 second.
c) program sleeps till the time difference from start is **exactly** 0.1 second.
d) repeats forever.

If the sleep time is a bit higher than 0.1 second, say 0.105 seconds, I am losing 0.005 seconds per second. This inaccuracy costs in my application, as I am losing in a day period: 0.005*3600*24 = 432 seconds.

My application is a realtime one; the time I am losing, is not of low importance.

---

Execution:

a) the a step was simple, just set a variable `x = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();`
b) run the function
c)

```
while((std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-x).count() < 1000000)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));
```

d) just loop

---

Summary:

a) i understand, no matter what, I will lose at least 1 nanosecond per second.
b) after reading those articles: [first](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6900), [second](ftp://ftp.cs.umanitoba.ca/pub/IPDPS03/DATA/W02_WPDRTS_29.PDF) I realize, it's possible to make my application lose just 30 microseconds per second = 0.00003 second. This means, in a day: 0.00003*3600*24 = 2.592 seconds per day.
c) at the moment using the function descibed above the best I managed is losing 7 minutes per day.

---

**What I am really trying to do:**

I am given access to a server with one limitation: Only one request per 0.1 second is allowed. If it takes less, they will ban me. If my request take longer, I am downloading less data. My application downloads a file every 0.1 seconds. If due to delays I lose 432 seconds per day, this means I could have downloaded 4320 files more.

**Q:** How to implement CPU shielding on CentOS preferable, or any other OS?

Comment: _'My application is a realtime one'_ What exactly does this mean? Do you have to fulfill some specific timing accuracy to control devices? In this case you don't need to care about overall loss. In order not to loose exact time from pov having a reference point, you'll need to synchronize with exact external sources at a specific rate.

Comment: I don't know what support for this there is in the C++ libraries, but with Posix timer functions, you specify the absolute expiry time, rather than the delta (you can also specify the repetition interval).  That would immediately solve your problem.

Comment: Once you do have that precise external source, you will also probably want to wake up just _ahead_ of your deadline and busywait until your deadline.  So, if your wakeup penalty has a maximum penalty `x`, then you'll want to wake up no later than `deadline - x`, and busywait until your deadline.  If you can't characterize `x` exactly, then you'll have to make a conservative estimate.

Comment: thanks, you have a good point, see the updated question above

Comment: @Blazer So if all you need is to hit a time slot of 0.1s, why in all the world are you bothering around with nanosecond accuracy? I don't really get it. They're requiring you not to sent more than one request within 0.1s, but not to time the distance between your requests being **exactly** 0.1s right?

Comment: I am download data 24/7 and need to get as much as possible, that's why I am trying to get it exactly at 0.1 second.

Comment: That's 0.1 second by _their_ clock, not yours.  How are you so sure they're that much better than you at measuring time?

Comment: @Blazer So you mean, if your request is issued a tick later, you'll see data loss? Do you have a fixed size for the data read?

Comment: True, I test it with the code in my post and works. Not I can't be 100% sure but I will try the best a human can do.

Comment: What kind of data is that? Does it expire?

Comment: Losing 3 seconds a day is less than 0.0035%.  Are you certain you need that last 0.0035%?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: No. Its simple: I am downloading one file every 0.1 seconds. If due to delays I lose 432 seconds per day, this means I could have downloaded 4320 files more.

Comment: Following on from Joe's point about who's measuring time, how can this limit possibly be taking into account latency jitter across the network connection?  Regardless of how accurately you wake up, your packets will arrive at the server with some non-negligible variance.

Comment: Does the server generate 1 000 000 files per day? What is it, 4chan archive?

Comment: Oli nailed the point I was hinting at.  Suppose you download 863999 files one day and 864001 the next because of network jitter.  Are you suddenly banned?  The framing time on a typical IP connection has way too much jitter.  Why the crazy tolerances here?  Also, who defines the day boundaries, and what happens when _their_ clock drifts even if yours is perfect?

Comment: Take a look at this great page in the NTP FAQ and ask yourself if you can do better than scientists synchronizing time over networks:  http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-sw-clocks-quality.htm

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: The execution of the function and the downloading take together less than 0.1 second. **This works.** Even using two servers in order to fix the jitter problem is not an issue (each server downloads once per 0.2 seconds).

Comment: @Blazer: I fully believe that it takes less than 0.1 seconds.  But you seem to misunderstand the point that Joe and I are making.  You are saying that you will get banned if you run faster than 0.1 seconds; we are saying that no matter how accurate you make your loop, you will **always** see (A) variance and (B) drift at the other end of the connection.  What kind of service is enforcing such precise constraints?  (Put another way, I don't believe that this is the real constraint ;) )

Comment: I understand your point guys. I really can't be sure what the guys at the other end are doing, but to be honest, I can only try my very best to make the application as good as possible. I am no God and machines are not perfect. I am just trying to download as much as possible. **Banning is just for a few seconds.** If I try the code and see they ban me, well, I will just change it. **With the code I provided they simply don't ban me.**

Comment: I know, it seems like I am trying to do the impossible here but really solving this will improve my application overall.

Comment: I can't believe they measure time between requests on a per request basis, but rather the number of requests from the same source over some period of time (or ensuring it took no less than X seconds to get Y requests). In other words, you could probably send 5 requests, wait half a second, send another 5 requests, just as well as you could send 1 request every 0.1s.

Comment: Here is today's summary of my `ping` statistics against Google's DNS server: `round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 52.683/165.997/337.376/91.659 ms`. Just the _standard deviation_ is about equal to your backoff period of 0.1s. The truth is that packets will take different routes over the network and will be delayed relative to each other, thus screwing with their arrival time at the server, the only thing that matters. It's unlikely you will be able to get within a factor of two from 0.1s/request without quite frequent temp-bans, unless your stddev is much lower than mine. Try this yourself!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to lose time over the day, you wouldn't implement your code like this.  You would do something like

```
for(long next = System.currentTimeMillis() + 100;; start += 100) {
    // do something
    while(true){
        long delay = next - System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (delay <= 0)
            break;
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

This way you can get jitter of up to 5 ms on bare metal machine and 50 ms on a hypervisor, but this will disappear in the next iteration or the one after.

i.e. there is no cumulative drift in this code. (Note: the high resolution timers drift but this is down to your hardware)

I suspect you are actually trying to solve a different problem you haven't really explained here.

> How to implement CPU shielding on CentOS preferable, or any other OS?

What I do for Java is

- use isocpus=5,6,11,12 or each CPU for each core you want to isolate. I suggest isolating whole cores. This allows you to use hyperthreading selectively.
- configure IRQ balance to avoid these CPU unless you intend to use them in your thread on this CPU.
- use sched_setaffinity to bind selected threads to individual CPUs. To allocate a whole core, leave one CPU of the core idle.

BTW I recommend busy waiting rather than using sleep or anything which blocks in the OS as this disturbs the CPU caches. i.e. your code will run significantly slower (2-5x) after waking as the wake time is not the only thing you have to worry about.

BTW2 I haven't found a reliable way to CPU shield on Windows other than setting to priority as high as possible, note: you cannot raise the priority unless you are running as an administrator.  On Linux, raising the priority is not as effective as removing the CPU from normal scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

Java has built in functionality to do this, one of the options with a `ScheduledExecutorService` is to schedule at a fixed **rate** or with fixed **delay**.

If you use the fixed rate option then it will give you exactly the behaviour you are looking for, the time it took to run this time will be subtracted from the delay before it runs again.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Note however that windows is a non-realtime OS running with pre-emptive multi tasking. The service will try and call you back as soon as possible after the next time comes but it is absolutely impossible to guarantee to do so. The only way to avoid that would be to switch to a realtime OS, but that is overkill here really.

Comment: I would add a link from Java 7 given Java 6 is basically EOL.

Comment: Good point, done that (that particular class hasn't changed but it is still better to point to the more current docs).

Comment: This answer tend to stay for years +1 btw.

Comment: Thanks, I will also, check this out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to control CPU usage the user them self can control it. By using task manager in Windows. I beleive you will have to mess with the task manager in your program code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried setting priority to realtime on a windows system. It helped **a bit**, but only one windows 7. Still far cry from what I am trying to do.